# Team bonding - ideas please

Tags: recruitment, team, teamwork

Can you please share some ideas of a great team bonding experience? We are looking to book an activity for the team to start in the best possible way this year. We are a team of 9 working in recruitment based in central London.It could be from an all day out to a thing of a couple of hours. Please let me know if you have any good ideas. Thank you!

Comment: https://toughmudder.co.uk/

Comment: @RichardU - The only time I'd be scared stiff of you is if you told me "I am Richard, and I really, really want to help you" :)

Comment: how is this related to "How do I clear my part when I am blamed for my team member's fault?" ?

Comment: Full contact cage fighting, with cheating allowed? :)

Comment: Give them interesting work to do, and don't compare them, so that they won't feel in competition.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't force people to participate in it. Once upon a time, a cocky colleague had this great idea to organize mandatory "team building" events, which involved wearing some silly hats and running around in various geometrical shapes (and bunch of similar sh**). I handed in my *resignation* 2 weeks later, and a few other folks followed shortly thereafter. The team building exercise was a resounding success, as they had to *rebuild* the team from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

1) Google "Team Building Events London"
2) Print out nine decent ideas
3) Put them in a hat
4) Ask youngest team member to draw an idea out of the hat
5) Go with it
6) Have fun